# Shopware 6 - Not using custom theme

Tags: twig, shopware

Hello for some reason shopware is not using my custom theme.
I followed the official example and ended up with the following path:

```
E:\XAMPP\htdocs\sw\custom\plugins\MyPlugin\src\Resources\views\storefront\layout\header\logo.html.twig
```

Unfortanetely, when now tying to compile the theme using

```
theme:compile
plugin:update MyPlugin
cache:clear
```

There is no visible change on the website. I made sure that the Storefront and the Headless sales channel are using my theme. Trough:

```
theme:change
```

and the just went trough the dialogue two times.

The code inside the template is as follows:

```
{% sw_extends '@Storefront/storefront/layout/header/logo.html.twig' %}

{% block layout_header_logo_link %}
    <h2>Hello world!</h2>
{% endblock %}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that the tool which autogenerates the plugin and theme dummy code, messes up the plugin name in the `theme.json` file, resulting in literally no behaviour.

Therefore, make sure that

```
"views": [
     "@Storefront",
     "@Plugins",
     "@myPlugin"
  ],
```

is changed to

```
"views": [
         "@Storefront",
         "@Plugins",
         "@MyPlugin"
      ],
```

Notice the change on the last line, make sure that the name matches your plugin name and then you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it is cache related so delete cache in settings or run command `psh.phar cache` in project root, u could also use command `bin/console cache:clear`

Comment: It is not cache related actually, the tool just creats a plugin template having the wrong name.